# how to not sort a HashSet values and allow duplicate?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, sharedpreferences, hashset

I am working on Android Project where I want to save an `arrayList` values into `sharedpreferences`

I don't want to sort or remove duplicate values from the list

I want the exact data in `arrayList` to be saved in `HashSet`

for example this is my arrayList Output:

```
D/waitingList﹕ [a, b, c, a, a, aa, cc]
```

but when I save it inside HashSet it sort

```
D/setWaiting﹕ [aa, a, b, cc, c]
```

and at sharedpreferences xml file like this

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<map>
    <int name="count_games" value="0" />
    <set name="setCurrent" />
    <set name="setWaiting">
        <string>a</string>
        <string>aa</string>
        <string>b</string>
        <string>c</string>
        <string>cc</string>
    </set>
</map>
```

I have to keep everything sorted as in the arrayList

this is my code:

```
public void saveArrayList(Context mContext, ArrayList<String> currentList, ArrayList<String> waitingList, int count)
    {
        SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
        SharedPreferences.Editor edit = pref.edit();

        HashSet<String> setCurrent = new HashSet<String>();
        setCurrent.addAll(currentList);
        Log.d("setCurrent",setCurrent.toString());
        Log.d("currentList",currentList.toString());

        HashSet<String> setWaiting = new HashSet<String>();
        setWaiting.addAll(waitingList);
        Log.d("setWaiting",setWaiting.toString());
        Log.d("waitingList",waitingList.toString());


        edit.putStringSet("setWaiting", setWaiting);
        edit.putStringSet("setCurrent", setCurrent);

        edit.putInt("count_games", count);

        edit.commit();


    }
```

Comment: How do you imagine saving duplicates into collection which does not allow duplicates ? Besides why would you use HashSet only to break its contract ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition, a Set cannot have duplicate values so you cannot do what you want.

Also HashSet doesn't preserve the order, if you want ordered set you can use [LinkedHashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) which preserves insertion order.

Comment: `putStringSet` mehtod accepts a Set so there is no way you can put duplicates.

Comment: alright, do you have any suggestion on the code to allow both?

Comment: An ArrayList allows both duplicate and ordered values but unfortunately the method you are using doesn't take List.

Comment: do you have another suggestion to save the ArrayList into (SOMETHING: file,sharedpreferences) then load it to the same ArrayList?